# In Javascript how to create a static property inside a constructor function?

Tags: javascript, function, constructor, static

I found it, we can declare the property directly on the constructor function as follow:

```
function Func(){}; 
Func.prop = "value";
```

the prop property is a static property which is available only on the constructor function(which play the role of a class)

Comment: Is this a question or an answer?

Comment: If you found the solution, you should post it below in **Your Answer**, not in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I found it, we can declare the property directly on the constructor function as follow:

function Func(){};
Func.prop = "value";
the prop property is a static property which is available only on the constructor function(which play the role of a class)